# Unable to initialize JCR_MOCK resource resolver factory - sling mocks

Tags: apache, unit-testing, mocking, jcr, sling

I have a simple sling mock test that is loading json data

```
public class Test {

    @Rule
    public final SlingContext context = new SlingContext(ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        context.load().json("/test-1.json", "/content/test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoad() {
        Resource resource = context.resourceResolver().getResource("/content/test");
    }
}
```

I have the following dependencies added to my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.testing</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.16</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When i execute this, I get the following exception, even though sling.api (v2.2) is an existing dependency in the pom

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize JCR_MOCK resource resolver factory.
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.ContextResourceResolverFactory.get(ContextResourceResolverFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.newResourceResolverFactory(SlingContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.setUp(SlingContextImpl.java:94)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.junit.SlingContext.access$000(SlingContext.java:32)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.junit.SlingContext$1.before(SlingContext.java:113)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceProviderFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.MockJcrResourceResolverFactory.getResourceResolverInternal(MockJcrResourceResolverFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.MockJcrResourceResolverFactory.getResourceResolver(MockJcrResourceResolverFactory.java:111)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.ContextResourceResolverFactory.initializeJcrMock(ContextResourceResolverFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.ContextResourceResolverFactory.get(ContextResourceResolverFactory.java:52)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceProviderFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 37 more
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a dependency on org.apache.sling.api ( as shown by a [search by class name on search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org%2Fapache%2Fsling%2Fapi%2Fresource%2FResourceProviderFactory%22) )