# How to Mock a RequestAttribute value in Sling Model

Tags: junit, mockito, aem, sling

I have a sling model adapted to @Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class) and have a request attribute,

> @RequestAttribute
> @Optional
> private boolean isRegistration = false;

now i wanted to Mock above parameter and test my code with true/false values. For that i tried below approaches but none of them are worked

```
   // register adapter factory
    BundleContext bundleContext = MockOsgi.newBundleContext();
    MockSling.setAdapterManagerBundleContext(bundleContext);
    // prepare sling request
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = MockSling.newResourceResolver(bundleContext);
    MockSlingHttpServletRequest request = new 
    MockSlingHttpServletRequest(resourceResolver);
    request.setAttribute("isRegistration", "true");
```

and,

```
    @Mock
    SlingHttpServletRequest slingHttpServletRequest;                             
    @Mock
    RequestParameter requestParameter;
Mockito.when(slingHttpServletRequest.getRequestParameter("isRegistration")).thenReturn(requestParameter);
        Mockito.when(requestParameter.getString()).thenReturn("true");
```

is there any other way to mock these kind of variables or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You will not get very far with using Mockito for Sling/AEM JUnit tests. It will be a never ending story to mock a pretty complex product - just for a few lines of code in your Sling model.

Better use [Sling Mocks](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html) or [AEM Mocks](https://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/index.html)!

Then your Sling Model:

```
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Default;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.RequestAttribute;

@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public class TestModel1 {

    @RequestAttribute
    @Default(booleanValues = false)
    private boolean isRegistration;

    public boolean isRegistration() {
        return isRegistration;
    }
}
```

Can be tested with this JUnit test based on Sling Mocks. AEM Mocks is almost the same, except it provides also many AEM services and features, to test against.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.apache.sling.models.factory.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.junit.SlingContext;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestModel1Test {

    @Rule
    public final SlingContext context = new SlingContext();

    private ModelFactory modelFactory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        context.addModelsForClasses(TestModel1.class);
        this.modelFactory = context.getService(ModelFactory.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void isRegistrationTrue() {
        context.request().setAttribute("isRegistration", true);
        TestModel1 model = modelFactory.createModel(context.request(), TestModel1.class);
        assertTrue(model.isRegistration());
    }

    @Test
    public void isRegistrationFalse() {
        context.request().setAttribute("isRegistration", false);
        TestModel1 model = modelFactory.createModel(context.request(), TestModel1.class);
        assertFalse(model.isRegistration());
    }

    @Test
    public void isRegistrationDefault() {
        TestModel1 model = modelFactory.createModel(context.request(), TestModel1.class);
        assertFalse(model.isRegistration());
    }
}
```

PS: Not sure, if you really want a @RequestAttribute-injector in your model. It is **NOT** a query parameter in Sling. See [here](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/request-parameters.html) for details.

Then your SlingModel should be

```
import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.request.RequestParameter;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.Self;

@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public class TestModel2 {

    @Self
    private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

    public boolean isRegistration() {
        return Optional.of(request)
                .map(req -> req.getRequestParameter("isRegistration"))
                .map(RequestParameter::getString)
                .map(BooleanUtils::toBooleanObject)
                .orElse(false);
    }
}
```

And the test would be:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.apache.sling.models.factory.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.junit.SlingContext;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestModelTest2 {

    @Rule
    public final SlingContext context = new SlingContext();

    private ModelFactory modelFactory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        context.addModelsForClasses(TestModel2.class);
        this.modelFactory = context.getService(ModelFactory.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void isRegistrationTrue() {
        context.request().setQueryString("isRegistration=true");
        TestModel2 model = modelFactory.createModel(context.request(), TestModel2.class);
        assertTrue(model.isRegistration());
    }

    @Test
    public void isRegistrationFalse() {
        context.request().setQueryString("isRegistration=false");
        TestModel2 model = modelFactory.createModel(context.request(), TestModel2.class);
        assertFalse(model.isRegistration());
    }

    @Test
    public void isRegistrationDefault() {
        TestModel2 model = modelFactory.createModel(context.request(), TestModel2.class);
        assertFalse(model.isRegistration());
    }
}
```

This is a minimal pom.xml to run the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>simpletest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock.junit4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick respone, but while 'context.request()....' i'm getting below exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to initialize RESOURCERESOLVER_MOCK resource resolver factory: org.apache.sling.testing.resourceresolver.MockResourceResolverFactoryOptions.setMangleNamespacePrefixes(Z)Lorg/apache/sling/testing/resourceresolver/MockResourceResolverFactoryOptions;" Thought of missing a dependency and added one(<artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.resourceresolver-mock</artifactId>), but still issue persists.

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978560/unable-to-initialize-jcr-mock-resource-resolver-factory-sling-mocks you are missing "org.apache.sling.api." But I need the full stacktrace to see.

Comment: I added a pom.xml that works for me.