# How to add mock for following in junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, aem, testcase

```
        propSet = childRes.getValueMap().keySet();
```

**Above code written in java can anyone help me to write mock in mockito in junit**

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You should add some context, at least. What is childRes? What do you want to mock, childRes or childRes.getValueMap() or childRes.getValueMap().keySet() ?

Comment: Mockito is the wrong approach for Sling/AEM JUnit tests. You will not get far, and it has little value. Search for "Sling Mocks" or "AEM Mocks". I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69674398/how-to-mock-a-requestattribute-value-in-sling-model/69675428#69675428

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the class type of the above object reference `childRes`.

For example:

```
Mockito.mock(ChildResponse.class);
```

Later you have to stub `getValueMap()`

```
Map<String> data = new HashMap<>();
// Populate some data into map
ChildResponse childRes = Mockito.mock(ChildResponse.class);
when(childRes.getValueMap()).thenReturn(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Map data = new HashMap<>();// add data to it
YOUR_CLASS_NAME childRes = Mokito.spy(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class);//Mokito.mock(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class);
Mockito.when(childRes.getValueMap()).thenReturn(map);
```

The difference is that in mock, you are creating a complete mock or fake object while in spy, there is the real object and you just spying or stubbing specific methods of it. ... While in spy objects, of course, since it is a real method, when you are not stubbing the method, then it will call the real method behavior.